# Oracle: check constraints are properly compiled?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Still learning the oracle, today we got one instance that, one of the trigger was compiled with dirty code, so at run time it threw an exception.(on Production Server)

so I just want to know that Is there any way to know that constraints as well as trigger are properly compiled?, just to avoid more instances like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you mean by dirty code as errors right ? To know trigger or procedures which they are compiled with warning, check user_errors table:

```
select * from user_errors where name= '<procedure or trigger name>'
```

as for constraints (Primary key , foreign key , default values) they dont get created if they contains error.